# Hitting time of a time varying threshold

Tags: random-variables, martingales, random-walk

Let $\{X_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be set of i.i.d. random variables. Define $Z_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i  $. I am looking for an upper bound for $\displaystyle \text{Pr} \left( Z_s \geq a \sqrt{s} \text{ for some } s \leq N \right)$.

One simple way is to use the union bound but I am looking for a tighter bound. I have looked up a number of resources for random walk (or martingale) hitting a threshold, but almost all of them have shown for a constant threshold. It seems that such a bound for time varying threshold should not be uncommon but I have not been able to figure a neat way of getting a tighter bound.

The random variables can be assumed to be subgaussian with known variance parameter. However, they need not be bounded almost surely. Also both $a$ and $N$ are assumed to be known.

Any references or hints will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Part of the trouble with your specific question would be that as $N$ increases, this goes to $1$ for every $a$ (see the law of the iterated logarithm). This convergence is slow, but one should expect the probabilities to be $\Omega(1)$ for large $N$. For upper bounds - this might be too strong but it's a tool I've recently picked up so everything looks like a nail... - since you have subGaussian increments, chaining should recover statements like $P(\max_{s \le N} Z_s/\sqrt{s} \ge a + C\sqrt{\log\log N}) \le e^{-a^2/C}$ for large enough $a$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Oh I had totally forgotten about the law of iterated logarithm. Thanks for reminding me! Yeah I read it up again and I see why the probability would become $\Omega(1)$. But with LIL we just get that the event will happen infinitely often (and for infinite $N$) but I am still curious as to how to find the first hitting time in the case where the threshold varies with time. Do you have any references for that?

Comment: I don't have references, sorry. I'll try to keep an eye out though. Incidentally, the chaining estimate I mentioned above does give some control on the hitting time (be warned that I haven't proved the above, it just seems like the correct form), in particular lower bounds of the form $\mathbb{E}[T_a] \ge \exp(\exp(a^2/C')).$ In contrast the union bound would give something like $\mathbb{E}[T_a] \ge \exp(\Omega(a^2))$.

Comment: I did some searching - https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200513456 seems like a good place to start. I flicked through some of the papers citing this on google scholar, and there seems to be a lot of relevant stuff. (BTW - there seems to be a typo in thm. 1 - (ii) should be $\lim_{c \to 0}$)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks a lot! I just glanced through the paper and it looks helpful. I will also go through the google scholar citations. Also, from what I tried, $\mathbb{E}[T_a] \leq O(\exp(\exp(a^2/C')))$ so I think the expected time is about in that range. Thanks! :)

Comment: I recently came across this paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.03204 - which seems germane to the above for two reasons - 1) they show nice tricks to turn linear bounds into curves (which, incidentally, I found strangely reminiscent of the chaining trick ), and 2) they show some non-asymptotic LIL type things that seem useful. Note that the paper does much more, which you may also find interesting. Here's a talk by one of the authors - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=po0EsW-ixig .

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks a lot for the paper! I also read it sometime ago and found it to be interesting especially how they fit things in a sort of generic framework. Thanks for the talk as well! I'll watch that too. :)

Comment: Oh, I just started reading the paper (I had only seen the talk), and I realised that the curved boundary stuff is in this paper - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08240.pdf - see Thm. 1. And you're welcome, of course. And while I'm at it - thanks for asking this Q, it's lead to a fair bit of fun for me!